# If statement for displaying content based on In App Purchase

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I have added In App Purchasing to my iOS app and am now trying to add an if statement that tells the app to show different content based on whether the product has been purchased or not

My code in viewDidLoad is like this:

```
    SKProduct * product = (SKProduct *) [_products self];
[_priceFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];


if ([[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] productPurchased:product.productIdentifier]) {


    labelPrice.text = @"Purchased";


} else {


    labelPrice.text = @"Not Purchased";


}
```

The problem is whenever the app is loading, regardless of whether item is purchased or not it is showing 'Not Purchased'

Is there another simple way to check if the user has made the purchase?

Comment: It seems the relevant code is in the `productPurchased:` method. If you want help you need to provide relevant details about that method.

Comment: BTW - have you actually taken the time to debug your code and see why `productPurchased:` always returns `NO`?

Answer (score 0):

`productPurchased:` (if you're using the IAPHelper from a tutorial) simply checks if a product is contained inside an array or not.

How are you populating that array? (i.e.: How is `[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance]` implemented?

When I used it, I populated my products and inited IAPHelper (shown below) with it and then it initialized the products purchased via NSUserDefaults:

```
- (id)initWithProductIdentifiers:(NSSet *)productIdentifiers {

    if ((self = [super init])) {

        // Store product identifiers
        _productIdentifiers = productIdentifiers;

        // Check for previously purchased products
        _purchasedProductIdentifiers = [NSMutableSet set];
        for (NSString * productIdentifier in _productIdentifiers) {
            BOOL productPurchased = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:productIdentifier];
            if (productPurchased) {
                [_purchasedProductIdentifiers addObject:productIdentifier];
                NSLog(@"Previously purchased: %@", productIdentifier);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Not purchased: %@", productIdentifier);
            }
        }

        // Add self as transaction observer
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

    }
    return self;

}
```

Then productPurchased just checks that array:

```
- (BOOL)productPurchased:(NSString *)productIdentifier {
    return [_purchasedProductIdentifiers containsObject:productIdentifier];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand that but imagine I have another view controller where I want to show content after purchase, what if statement would I add there?

Comment: You're doing it the right way in a VC. That's not the point. If productsPurchased is returning NO, that means the array does not contain your purchase yet. Try debugging into the code I displayed to make sure the products are getting added appropriately.